# Как вернуться к начальному состоянию редюсера в redux конкретного свойства?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Есть начальное состояние

```js
const initialState = {
    filter_models: {
      adventure_state: null,
      type_id: null,
    }
}
```

после определенных действий свойство **type_id** изменилось, как откатиться назад к начальному состоянию только свойства **type_id** не затрагивая другие?

Answer (score 0):

Если говорить про redux то необходимо создать и вызвать экшен, который будет сбрасывать необходимое вам поле в нужное значение.

Это может выглядеть так:

actions.js:

```
export function resetTypeId() {
  return { type: consts.RESET_TYPE_ID };
}
```

Далее необходимо вызвать этот экшен, в нужный вам момент

app.js:

```
import * as actions from './actions';
...
this.props.dispatch(actions.resetTypeId());
```

Ну и конечно нужно дописать reducer, который будет обрабатывать этот экшен и менять state приложения

reducer.js:

```
function App(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    ...
    case consts.RESET_TYPE_ID:
      return {...state, type_id: null};
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Детальнее почитать и найти ряд примеров можно по ссылке https://redux.js.org/

Answer (score 0):

Можно пойти вот таким путём, создав для каждой ноды стейта свой редьюсер со своей логикой обновления ноды:

```
// index.js с рутовым редьюсером
import { adventureStateReducer, typeIdReducer } from 'reducers/filterModels';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  filter_models: combineReducers({
    adventure_state: adventureStateReducer,
    type_id: typeIdReducer
  }
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Сброс состояния осуществить диспатчем `dispatch('RESET_ADVENTURE_STATE')` или `dispatch('RESET_TYPE_ID')` в зависимости от того, какую ноду нужно "обнулить":

```
// reducers/filterModels.js:
export const adventureStateReducer = (state = null, action) => {
    if (action.type === ...) {
        return action.payload;
    }
    if (action.type === 'RESET_ADVENTURE_STATE') {
        return null;
    }
    // ...
    return state;
};

export const typeIdReducer = (state = null, action) => {
    if (action.type === ...) {
        return action.payload;
    }
    if (action.type === 'RESET_TYPE_ID') {
        return null;
    }
    // ...
    return state;
};
```

Первичное значение нод храниться в дефолтных значениях функций-редьюсерах `state = null`